# How to convert a Dell Service Tag to an Express Service Code?

Tags: dell

When calling Dell Support, you usually have to enter the "Express Service Code" of your system get a tech on the phone.

This is because the Service Tag (= serial number) is not exclusively made of digits, but the Express Service Code is ([DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTMF) friendly).

I'm only storing the ST in my inventory, so is there a way to convert a Dell ST to an Express Service Code?

Comment: Dell used to have a program called `Dell Express Service Code Utility` that would do this but sadly I'm unable to find it online anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dell Service Tag is just a base 36 number (10 digits + 26 letters). If you convert it to a base 10 number, you get the Express Service Code.

To do so, from a `python` console you can just type (credits to *MikeyB*):

```python
int("SRVCTAG",36)
```

Also, here is a simple PHP web page for doing so.

```php
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Conversion Service Tag => Express Service Code (Dell)</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Conversion Service Tag => Express Service Code (Dell)</h1>

<p>
<form action="" method="get">
Service Tag : <input type="text" name="st" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['st']) ? $_GET['st'] : ''; ?>" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input type="submit" value="Get Express SC" />
</form>
</p>

<?php
if( isset($_GET['st']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['st']) && strlen($_GET['st']) == 7 ) {
    $st = strtoupper($_GET['st']);
    $esc = base_convert($st, 36, 10); // convert from base 36 to base 10
    echo "<p>Express Service Code : $esc</p>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

<sup>*I am licensing this code under the [GNU GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) licence version 2 or above, and the [licence used on the stackexchange network](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#2NetworkContent), whichever you prefer.*</sup>

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but by posting here you agreed to the terms of services (http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) which states that your content is CC licensed. If you want it under the GPL you shouldn't post here.

Comment: Here's the [python equivalent](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/dell-express-service-code/post-ae1b85d8-d25e-11e2-bc00-02911874f8c8/): `str(int(service_tag,36))`

Comment: @faker Hence, this content is dual licenced *de facto*. It never was *exclusive* licencing, I clarified that in my answer. I notice however, that the stackexchange network barely respect other people copyrights, especially for posts copy-pasting non-free content.

Comment: @Totor: If you notice copyright infringement then please flag it and explain it - the mods on SF take this seriously.

Comment: @Iain I can assure you they don't, flagged or not. The [official policy here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114928) is mostly to "let go until some serious and official/legal action is taken from the copyright older". See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/468109) flagged multiple time for example: still here. You're saying SF is an exception?

Comment: You can also do the reverse and get the service tag from the express service code by swapping the 10 and the 36 in the PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of sites that would do this... Google is your answer, but here is a few direct from Dell site themselves..

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/my_systems_info/express_service_code?DoNotRedirect=y

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/Expressservice

Comment: Thanks I didn't know those. It makes you dependant of a webservice you don't master though. This can be a problem if you're in a situation where you must contact the support *because* you don't have Internet access anymore.